# MERGE statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, merge-statement

I have a table `student(int ID, nvarchar(10) studentName)`
and a table user type `myStudentType (int ID, nvarchar(10) studentName)`

I need to create a stored procedure that accepts a `myStudentType` parameter (`@students`) and a parameter `@newname`

```
mySp(@students myStudentType, @newname nvarchar(10))
```

and merges `myStudentType` with student so that all the rows with ids that exists on both tables will now in student table have for the `studentName` - `@newname` (the parameter)
and the sp will return a list of all the records from @students that were not updated in 
the student table

What is the best way to do that (preferred with merge)

thanks

Comment: i have only the part using the merge to update all the rows in students table... i dont know how to get all the recordes that were not updated in the param to the sp

Answer (score 0):

The part of the spec that I think will be most problematic is:

> the sp will return a list of all the records from @students that were not updated in the student table

I assume by 'list' the spec implies 'table' (T-SQL has no concept of a 'list' type). An output parameter cannot be a `TABLE` type (including user-defined table types). While a function can return a table, you cannot update base tables via a function. For more details and possible solutions, see [How to Share Data Between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) by  by Erland Sommarskog.